# Add a category column to dataset based on some statuses in another column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a 'status' column for every 'workflow'.  Status can be one of 'Ran', 'Successful' , 'Failed'. Please note every workflow that runs will have 'Ran' status, and there will be separate rows in the table to describe the end result of workflow, i.e. whether it 'Failed' or 'Succeeded', its even possible that nothing was captured as final status of the workflow.

I only want to filter the rows that had 'Ran' status, and add one more column to such rows that will divide the number of 'Ran' rows into three categories (I am only interested in right proportion of 'Ran' rows being assigned to these categories) - 'Successful', 'Failed', 'Unknown'. Since all the statuses are captured in the same column, I am having a hard time writing a query for this. Please note that I only want to use status column, because other columns are unreliable

Sample Table Data:

```
status
------
Ran
Ran
Ran
Ran
Ran
Successful
Failed
Ran
Ran
Failed
```

Desired Output:

```
status  category
-------+--------
Ran     'Failed'
Ran     'Failed'
Ran.    'Successful'
Ran.    'Unknown'  
Ran.    'Unknown'
Ran     'Unknown'
Ran.    'Unknown'
```

As you see above - I filter the results only by rows that had 'Ran' status, but I add another column with number of 'Failed' statuses (2) in original data leading to 'Categiory' of 2 rows being 'Failed'. Any left over number of 'Ran' after filling 'Failed' and 'successful' are assigned 'Unknown' category. It does not matter to me which row I pick to assign a category as long as number of rows are good. I know for a fact that number of 'Ran' rows will always be greater than sum of Failed' and Successful rows.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using Redshift. Added the tag,

Comment: So you don't have a workflowId which you can use to group by? Isn't it just enough to count the number of Failed, Successful and Ran. With these numbers you have all your information (Unknown=Ran-Failed-Successful).

Comment: @Conffusion thank you, so the workflowid is not there for each record (its not enforced since its redshift. And the problem is that I really need the resultset in this format above for a visualization and internal downstream dependency. I can write a query like below for the numbers as you said but need results in the format above.
select 
SUM(CASE when status = 'Ran' then 1 else 0 end) as Run,
SUM(CASE when status = 'Successful' then 1 else 0 end) as Successful,
(SUM(CASE when status = 'Ran' then 1 else 0 end) - SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'Ran' THEN 1 else 0 end)) as Unknown

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  Without such a column, your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the performance but this may work:

```
SELECT status, 
       case when r <= (select count(*) from runs where status = 'Failed') then 'Failed'  
            when (r > (select count(*) from runs where status = 'Failed') and r <= (select count(*) from runs where status in ('Failed','Successful'))) then 'Successful' 
            else 'Unknown'
       end as category
FROM (
   SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS R, 
     runs.* 
   FROM runs
   WHERE status = 'Ran'
) as result
```

Tested with Apache derby but I hope you get the idea. ROW_NUMBER also exists in RedShift.

My output:

```
STATUS CATEGORY
Ran    Failed
Ran    Failed
Ran    Successful
Ran    Unknown
Ran    Unknown
Ran    Unknown
Ran    Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  Let met assume you have two more columns `workflowid` and `timestamp`.  You want this information *per* workflow based on the timestamp.

Then:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(case when status in ('Successful', 'Failed' then timestamp end) over (partition by workflowid order by timestamp) is null
             then 'Failed'
             when timestamp >= min(case when status = 'Successful'then timestamp end) and
                  timestamp < min(case when status = 'Failed' then timestamp end)
             then 'Successful'
             else 'Unknown'
         end) as new_status
from t
```